# Adding In App Purchase (subscription) to iOS app - not able to test ("Invalid product ID")

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, urbanairship.com

I've been struggling for some time with adding In App Purchase to an existing iOS app. First, some background:

---

## Background

The app have been on the App Store for some time and it has quite a few users. The app uses push (successfully) and is also activated for In App purchase in the developer portal (have been since first version of the app).

Now the goal is to implement subscriptions (auto-renewable) using Urban Airship.

---

## Problem

The subscription product has been added to both iTunes Connect and Urban Airship and I've double and tripple checked that the product ID is identical.

*But I still get "INVALID PRODUCT ID"*

**Update #1**
To answer V1ru8's comment: I've been testing at three different occasions. I removed and re-added the product to both iTunes Connect and Urban Airship about a week ago, and tested a couple of minutes ago.

My subscription product is marked "Ready to submit" in iTunes Connect. I've also added a screenshot.

I've read tons of information and documentation on the subject (http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/, http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/, to mention a few) but still, some questions remains unanswered:

- Do I have to submit a version of my app, with the In-App Purchase product, for approval, to be able to test it? (Apple states that "Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.", but doesn't mention whether it applies to testing or not)
- Is there any other things that might cause this error, that is specific to subscriptions?

If I've missed to add some information, write a comment and I'll update the question ASAP.

Thanks in advance!

---

### Update

Maybe V1ru8 was onto something. All of a sudden I get my subscription product listed. I will try some buying and other testing to see if that's working too.

Comment: In what interval did you test it? I had the same problem a lot a times. Normally for me the problem was gone when testing it the next day. It looks like the sandbox is not really reliable.

Comment: Updated the question to answer your input. Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe V1ru8 comment was the simple answer. Perhaps you could write it as a more conclusive answer, which I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same behavior a few times when implementing In App Purchases. I could solve it every time by waiting for some time and trying again. For me it took up to 3 days to work. The App store sandbox is not really reliable. So when you've checked your ID's twice and it's still not working just wait a day or two and magically it will work.